# How Java TreeSet are implemented

Tags: tree, implementation, treeset

I was wondering how a TreeSet is implemented in Java. In fact, I was wondering, is a TreeSet using, under the hood, a balancing tree, or is it using an array ?

In other word, when I am adding an element to my treeSet, I know it will be ordered, but will it will be:

- add in an array, which mean that when my array is full, it will need to create a new array and copy all element from the old one to the new one.
- add at a random spot in the memory and linked to the element before it and after it ? If so, is it balancing the element, so the "top" of the tree is alway at the middle of the element, or is it just adding "leaf" where it fit, resulting in a "linear" tree ?

It has been a while since I study data structure, so just let's me know if my question make no sens or is not well explained.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java's `TreeSet` uses a `TreeMap`, which is backed by a [red-black tree](https://github.com/ZenOfAutumn/jdk8/blob/master/java/util/TreeMap.java). So, mostly the second option, but [red-black trees are self-balancing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) so you won't run into the pathological "linear" case even if you insert elements in ascending/descending order.